# Executing functions on click is not working in sveltekit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I follow a [tutorial](https://svelte.dev/repl/0091c8b604b74ed88bb7b6d174504f50?version=3.35.0) how to create toast messages. I have to bind the message to the addToast method when I click the submit button. If you look at these two lines of code.

```
    <button on:click={console.log(form?.message)}>Login</button>
    <button on:click={() => addToast({ form?.message })}>Login</button>
```

There is not much of a difference, but the first one works perfectly, while the other one returns an error that the keyword form is an unexpected token..
What is the difference between them and why doesn't it work like the console.log?

This is the addToast method:

```
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

export const toasts = writable([]);

export const addToast = (toast) => {
    const id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000);

    const defaults = {
        id,
        type: 'success',
        dismissible: true,
        timeout: 5000
    };

    toasts.update((all) => [{ ...defaults, ...toast}, ...all]);

    if (toast.timeout) setTimeout(() => dismissToast(id), toast.timeout);
}

export const dismissToast = (id) => {
    toasts.update((all) => all.filter(t => t.id !== id ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addToast({ form?.message })` is not valid javascript.

If you need to pass an object with a key named `message` to `addToast`, do so:

```js
addToast({ message: form?.message })
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two lines of code is that the first one is directly logging the value of `form?.message` to the console, while the second one is trying to pass the value of `form?.message` as an argument to the `addToast` function.

The reason the first line of code works is because the `console.log` function is simply evaluating the expression `form?.message` and then printing the result to the console. This expression is valid because it is using the optional chaining operator (`?.`), which will only return the value of `form.message` if form exists and is not null or undefined.

The reason the second line of code does not work is because the `addToast` function expects an object as its argument. The expression `form?.message` does not return an object, so the compiler is throwing an error.

To fix the second line of code, you need to wrap the expression `form?.message` in an object literal. This will create an object with a single property, `message`, whose value is the value of `form?.message`.

Here is the corrected code:

```
<button on:click={() => addToast({ message: form?.message })}>Login</button>
```